# Tensorflow worked on M1 Mac. CPU/mem use

Tags: tensorflow, apple-m1

I successfully installed tensorflow on my M1 Macbook air. Then I load up a previous script for testing. It works. But when I check the Activity Monitor, it shows CPU always have 66~71% Idle, memory is 14G used/16G total.

Why I can't use all the CPU ability? Does the Memory short board the performance?